# main.kt:4:1: error: a 'return' expression required in a function with a block body ('{...}')

Tags: kotlin

Я пока начинающий в Kotlin. Поэтому не могу разобраться как можно исправить эту ошибку. прошу Вас помочь.

```
fun  checkClient(client : String):{ // и здесь почему-то(наверно нужно что-то вернуть)
    when {
        client == "dog" -> throw DogException()
        client == "cat" -> throw CatException()
    }
}// ошибка тут

class DogException() : Exception()
class CatException() : Exception()
fun main (args: Array<String>){
    checkClient("dog")
}
```

Comment: у Вас синтаксическая ошибка, `:` не нужно после объявления функции, если она не должна ничего возвращать (Замените `):{` на `){`)

Comment: Спасибо Вам больше за помощь!